# Death by a thousand cut(scenes)

Tags: mass-effect-3

So, during the opening sequence, I was out of cover getting shot at when the Normandy came to pick myself and the Admiral up. When the cutscene began, and my camera was locked into watching the Normandy arrive, I was still being shot at, and just before the full cutscene started (ie the part that didn't just take control of my camera but was a custom scene) I was just about to die. I'm curious if anyone has died in this manner, and if so, what happens? Does it glitch, does the cutscene play, or does it count as a death and just handle it the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me once on Palaven. I'd just finished a fight with a big brute, which triggered one of those in-game cutscenes where an NPC started jabbering at me. I was low on health at the time though and when he started talking a husk near me decided to chew what was left of my face off.

After I died, I hit "Resume" to continue, thinking I'd have to redo the fight. Instead, it had me load at a point just after the NPCs dialog. I actually ended up loading a quicksave from a while back and redoing part of the level just so I'd be able to hear the NPC's dialog after killing the brute.

That said, it's a pretty rare occurrence where this sort of thing can happen, and I'm betting it's even odds if it will restore you to a point just before or just after the cutscene.